# Invalid Literal for Int Error with csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

After trying and failing with solutions given here...I now present my problem:

I have a csv which was imported from multiple txt-files and currently the dtype is str in all columns. 
For sorting my data I need one column to be int again but converting doesn't work as I hoped. I'm using Pandas.
I tried different approaches. Firsty, loading the data with a converter:

```
df = pd.read_csv('501-1000.csv', sep='\t', header=None, index_col=False, names=cols, usecols=cols,converters={"PY":int})
```

and using `df["PY"].astype(int)`. In both cases I got the `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'BA'`
Since I read that this has something to do with values that can't be converted to ints I tried `df.dropna(subset=['PY'])` and `df["PY"].fillna(0.0).astype(int)`
The results didn't change.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Sadly checking my rows by hand is not really an option - In my test-file, maybe, but it's just to much data to do that.
The full traceback when trying the converter is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d5ea8aa389dc> in <module>()
     16 # load data; note dtype not set to str since there appear to be numeric columns
     17 cols = ['TI', 'AB', 'PY', 'DI']
---> 18 df = pd.read_csv('501-1000.csv', sep='\t', header=None, index_col=False, names=cols, usecols=cols,converters={"PY":int})
     19 
     20 # cycle through filename_dict, slice and export to csv

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    653                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    654 
--> 655         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    656 
    657     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    409 
    410     try:
--> 411         data = parser.read(nrows)
    412     finally:
    413         parser.close()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1003                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
   1004 
-> 1005         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1006 
   1007         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1746     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1747         try:
-> 1748             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1749         except StopIteration:
   1750             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:10862)()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:11138)()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:12175)()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:14103)()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._apply_converter (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:30638)()

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'BA'
```

If I missed something, let me know, I'm both rather new to programming and this website and english isn't my first language either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, need omit `converters` and use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert not numeric to `NaN`s:

```
df = pd.read_csv('501-1000.csv',
                 sep='\t',
                 header=None, 
                 index_col=False, 
                 names=cols, 
                 usecols=cols)

df["PY"] = pd.to_numeric(df["PY"], errors='coerce').fillna(0.0).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this works in theory. But for some reason it seems every row throws an error and well...All rows filled with 0.0 isn't what I wanted. But I guess the problem lies deeper in my data, so still: thanks!

Comment: Check data, maybe traling whitespaces. Then need `df["PY"] = pd.to_numeric(df["PY"].str.strip(), errors='coerce').fillna(0.0).astype(int)`

Comment: Doesn't change it, sadly. I guess I'll try to look at the data closer. Could it be a problem that while importing I set dtype=str ? If I don't do that I get a "DtypeWarning: Columns (44) have mixed types." warning though..

Comment: Are data confidental?

Comment: No, nothing confidential.

Comment: Can you send me your csv to my email in my profile? I can check your data.

Comment: I'll send you a dropbox link once it's done uploading, might take a bit though.

Comment: very large data? I am curious ;)

Comment: Kind of. Send the mail out now :)

Comment: I got no email yet :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164085/discussion-between-seeamoebe-and-jezrael).